# How to disable end date options in angular material date range picker depending on the start date

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have this date range picker from Angular Material 15.
The picker works fine, I am able to select a start date and a end date and they display in the input's text field.
The only thing that is not working are the min and max values for end date.
Once start date has been chosen, I would like to have the calendar disable all dates that are ferther than 7 days from start date. How can I do this?

```
<!-- Date -->
  <mat-form-field style="width: 250px !important">
    <mat-label>Date</mat-label>
    <mat-date-range-input [rangePicker]="picker" (click)="picker.open()">
      <input
        matStartDate
        placeholder="Start date"
        [(ngModel)]="startDate"
        (ngModelChange)=" onSelectionChange()"
      />
      <input
        matEndDate
        placeholder="End date"
        [(ngModel)]="endDate"
        (ngModelChange)=" onSelectionChange()"
        [min]="testA"
        [max]="testB"
      />
    </mat-date-range-input>

    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker">
      <mat-icon matDatepickerToggleIcon>calendar_month</mat-icon>
    </mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-date-range-picker #picker ></mat-date-range-picker>
  </mat-form-field>
```

```
  startDate: string = null;
  endDate: string = null;

  testA: Date = null;
  testB: Date = null;

  onSelectionChange(): void {
    if (this.startDate) {
      const maxDate = new Date(this.startDate);
      const minDate = new Date(this.startDate);
      maxDate.setDate(maxDate.getDate() + 7);
      minDate.setDate(minDate.getDate() - 7);
      this.testB = maxDate;
      this.testA = minDate;
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, the implementation lacks the ability to apply validation exclusively to the "enddate" field. Upon selecting the initial date, the code effectively disables all subsequent days within a week's duration for the input. However, a limitation arises when attempting to modify the start date beyond the one-week mark from the initial selection. To address this issue, it is recommended to introduce a dedicated button that enables users to reset the input, facilitating the adjustment of the start date as desired. By implementing this enhancement, the user experience will be improved, ensuring greater flexibility and ease of use for the date selection process.

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  public startDate: string | undefined;
  public endDate: string | undefined;

  public maxEndDate: Date | undefined;
  public testB: Date | undefined;

  onSelectionChange(): void {
    if (this.startDate) {
      const maxDate = new Date(this.startDate);
      maxDate.setDate(maxDate.getDate() + 7);
      this.maxEndDate = maxDate;
    } else {
      this.maxEndDate = undefined;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<mat-form-field style="width: 250px !important">
  <mat-label>Date</mat-label>
  <mat-date-range-input
    [rangePicker]="picker"
    [max]="maxEndDate"
    (click)="picker.open()"
  >
    <input
      matStartDate
      placeholder="Start date"
      [(ngModel)]="startDate"
      (ngModelChange)="onSelectionChange()"
    />
    <input
      matEndDate
      placeholder="End date"
      [(ngModel)]="endDate"
      (ngModelChange)="onSelectionChange()"
    />
  </mat-date-range-input>

  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker">
    <mat-icon matDatepickerToggleIcon>calendar_month</mat-icon>
  </mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-date-range-picker #picker></mat-date-range-picker>
</mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to move the `[max]` and `[min]` attributes to the containing `mat-date-range-input`, as suggested here: [Min Date and Max Date not working Angular Material Range Input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63475980/min-date-and-max-date-not-working-angular-material-range-input)